# Finite dimensional cokernel of a map coming from a product Fedholm map

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$ be Banach spaces (if that helps I will be happy to assume they are Hilbert spaces) and let
\begin{align}
T_1 : X \rightarrow Y_1, \\
T_2 : X \rightarrow Y_2
\end{align} be bounded linear maps such that
$T:= T_1 \times T_2 : X \rightarrow Y_1 \times Y_2$ is a Fredholm map.

Is it true that $T_1|_{\ker T_2}$ is also Fredholm? Its kernel is finite-dimensional since it is the kernel of $T$ but why is the cokernel finite-dimensional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{P}(n)$ be the property: "For all Banach spaces $X$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, and for all $T_1 \in B(X, Y_1)$ and $T_2 \in B(X, Y_2)$, if $T_1 \times T_2$ is Fredholm with $\mathrm{codim}(\mathrm{ran}(T_1 \times T_2)) = n$, then $T_1|_{\ker T_2}$ is Fredholm."
As noted by OP, we need only focus on the cokernel or on the range (just a matter of preference) as the kernel of $T_1|_{\ker T_2}$ is already finite-dimensional.

**Initialisation with $n = 0$**: fairly simple, $\mathrm{codim}(\mathrm{ran}(T_1 \times T_2)) = 0$ is equivalent to saying that $T_1 \times T_2$ is surjective, thus its range contains $Y_1 \times \{0\}$, but that implies that $T_1|_{\ker T_2}$ is also surjective, thus Fredholm by the previous remark.

**Induction phase**: assume $\mathcal{P}(n)$ is true, and let's show that $\mathcal{P}(n+1)$ is also true.
Let $X$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $T_1$, and $T_2$ be as they should, with $\mathrm{codim}(\mathrm{ran}(T_1 \times T_2)) = n + 1$.
Define $\widetilde{X} := X \times \mathbb{K}$ ($\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), equipped with one of the usual product norms. Take $V$ an algebraic complement of $\mathrm{ran}(T_1 \times T_2)$ in $Y_1 \times Y_2$, let $(y_1,y_2) \in V$, and consider $V_0$ an algebraic complement of $\mathrm{span}\big((y_1, y_2)\big)$ in $V$, so that:
$$Y_1 \times Y_2 = \mathrm{ran}(T_1 \times T_2) \oplus \mathrm{span}\big((y_1, y_2)\big) \oplus V_0$$
with $V_0$ of dimension $n$, as $V$ is of dimension $n+1$ by assumption.
Consider now the linear maps $S_1 : \widetilde{X} \to Y_1$ and $S_2 : \widetilde{X} \to Y_2$ defined as follows:
$$\forall (x, \alpha) \in \widetilde{X},\quad (S_1 \times S_2)(x, \alpha) := (T_1 \times T_2)(x) + \alpha(y_1, y_2)$$
$S_1$ and $S_2$ are linear, and bounded because:
$$\|S_k(x,\alpha)\| = \|T_k(x) + \alpha y_k\| \leq \|T_k\|\|x\| + |\alpha| \|y_k\| \leq \max(\|T_k\|, \|y_k\|) \|(x,\alpha)\|$$
Moreover, $\ker(S_k) = \ker(T_k) \times \{0\}$, thus:
$$\ker(S_1 \times S_2) = \left(\ker(T_1)\times\{0\}\right) \cap \left(\ker(T_1)\times\{0\}\right) = \ker(T_1 \times T_2)\times\{0\}$$
and:
$$\mathrm{ran}(S_1 \times S_2) = \mathrm{ran}(T_1 \times T_2) \oplus \mathrm{span}\big((y_1, y_2)\big)$$
Hence, $S_1 \times S_2$ is Fredholm because $T_1 \times T_2$ is Fredholm, and $\mathrm{ran}(S_1 \times S_2)$ is complemented by $V_0$ of dimension $n$, therefore, by $\mathcal{P}(n)$, $S_1|_{\ker S_2}$ is Fredholm.
Now, we have:
$$\mathrm{ran}\left(S_1|_{\ker S_2}\right) = \mathrm{ran}\left(S_1|_{\ker T_2 \times \{0\}}\right) = \mathrm{ran}\left(T_1|_{\ker T_2}\right)$$
By the observation made prior to the induction, this implies that $T_1|_{\ker T_2}$ is Fredholm because $S_1|_{\ker S_2}$ is Fredholm, which means that $\mathcal{P}(n+1)$ holds assuming $\mathcal{P}(n)$ holds.

**Conclusion**: By induction, $\mathcal{P}(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, hence OP's claim holds.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $T$ has finite dimensional cokernel please? You say that $T_1, T_2$ are surjective, but that is in general not enough. Consider $Id\times Id$, which just gives you the diagonal (i.e. does not have finite codimension).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Good point, I did overlook that... I'll delete this answer if I can't salvage it.

Comment: I tried something similar and I did not manage to get it of finite cokernel. I start to believe that it is actually true.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think I've found the solution this time, I've edited my answer.

Comment: I have not read the whole answer yet. For $n=0$ how do you get that $T_1\vert_{\text{ker}(T_2)}$ is surjective? I see that $T_1$ must be surjective, but why is the restriction surjective too?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven To have all the elements of $Y_1 \times \{0\}$, the only possible case is that, on $\ker T_2$, $T_1$ covers all of $Y_1$.

Comment: Stupid me, we are by construction on the kernel of the second component. I'll read the rest latter. Thanks for the swift reply!

Comment: Very nice proof!

Comment: I have thought about it a bit more and came up with another proof, which I will post below. Please let me know if it is unclear or if I made a mistake. Thanks for the answer I will accept it now.

Answer (score 1):

To see that the cokernel is finite-dimensional, we first show that
\begin{equation}
Y_1 \times \{0\}/ Im(T|_{\ker T_2})
\end{equation} must be finite-dimensional. Since $Im(T|_{\ker T_2}) = Im T \cap (Y_1 \times \{0\})$ and using the second isomorphism theorem,
\begin{equation}
\frac{Y_1 \times \{0\}}{ Im(T|_{\ker T_2})} \cong \frac{Y_1 \times \{0\}}{ Im T \cap (Y_1 \times \{0\}) } \cong \frac{ Im T + (Y_1 \times \{0\} )}{ Im T} 
\end{equation}
which is finite dimensional since $T$ is Fredholm. Now observe that $T|_{\ker T_2} \cong (T_1|_{\ker T_2}) \times 0$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
Y_1 \times \{0\}/ Im(T|_{\ker T_2}) \cong Y_1 \times \{0\}/Im(T_1|_{\ker T_2}) \times \{0\} \cong Y_1/ Im (T_1|_{\ker T_2}).
\end{equation}

Comment: I think you forgot a "$Y_1 \times \{0\}/$" in your last line but otherwise this seems perfect!

Comment: fixed, thank you